# Mosaic of a layer in openlayer

Tags: openlayers, mapserver

I'm working with mapserver and openlayers, and I have a problem when I draw a WMS layer. I get a mosaic of this layer and I don't know why. Anybody can help me? My HTML code is:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
  controls: []
});
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('Municipios',
  "path of the map", {
    layers: "MUNICIPIO"
  }, {
    isBaseLayer: "true",
    visibility: "true"
  });
map.addLayer(wms);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

And my mapfile is:

```
MAP

NAME "mapa2"
SIZE 1400 900
IMAGETYPE png
IMAGECOLOR 196 240 255
EXTENT -16.0006 27.7281 -13.2323 29.3318
SHAPEPATH "datos"
FONTSET "path"

WEB 
    TEMPLATE "/mapserver/ms4w/apps/prueba/index.html"
    IMAGEPATH "/mapserver/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/"
    IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
    METADATA
                "WMS_TITLE" "mapa2"
        "WMS_SRS" "EPSG:4258"
    END
END

LAYER
    NAME Foto1
    TILEINDEX indice.shp
    TILEITEM location
    DATA Foto1
    TYPE RASTER
    STATUS on
    OFFSITE 252 252 252 
    METADATA
        WMS_NAME "Foto1"
        WMS_FORMAT "IMAGE/PNG"
        WMS_SRS "EPSG:4258"
    END
END

LAYER
    NAME    "MUNICIPIO"
    STATUS  ON
    DATA    MUNICIPIO
    LABELITEM "NOM_MUNICI"
    TYPE POLYGON
    CLASS
        STYLE
            COLOR 254 226 197
            OUTLINECOLOR    255 0 0
        END
        LABEL 
            SIZE SMALL
            COLOR 0 0 0
        END
    END
END
```

I want to put the raster layer too but I can't.

Comment: You should ask a moderator to migrate this question to http://gis.stackexchange.com, you're more likely to get help there.

Comment: @kryger, actually in the last 30 days, we have managed 0% unanswered on this tag. However, mapserver is a bit trickier, to diagnose, I agree :D

Comment: Are you saying you want a single tile but you are getting multiple tiles? You can set singletile:true as an options in the WMS constructor, which might help?

Comment: @user2898914 See the example here, starting at line 96, for the syntax. singleTile defuaults to false.

Comment: When I set single tile I can`t do zoom on it, I don't know why.

Comment: Do you have a resolution array in your OpenLayers.Map constructor? That is where the zoom levels come from.

Comment: It doesn't work, I've tried but no change.

Comment: Have you seen this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/single-tile.html?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but when I do it, I cant do zoom, it comeback to the same place.

Comment: I think the mapserver gave me the same picture to 2 differents request

Comment: I don't think the issue is with mapserver. Can you repeat your problem with a different data source (that is publicly available) and then post a full working example?

Comment: I fix it. I put openlayers.layer.mapserver instead of openlayers.layer.wms It's wrong?

Comment: I fix it with the wms layer. It was wrong the path to the map. Thank yoou.